# Css menu disappears too quickly when I move the mouse

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/4/

When I try to access menu items,menu disappears too quickly.How can I solve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed!
http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/14/

I just wrapped it in another div, and if you hover THAT, the menu will appear. My wrapper wraps the menu too, so if you leave the `<a>` you're still on the wrapper, keeping the menu visible.

Comment: you might wanna [turn the wrapper into an inline-level element](http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/24/), to avoid the side effect of poping the menu by hovering outside the top anchor.

Comment: @Eliran M. Can you show what you say on jsfiddle.I dont understand

Answer (score 4):

This is because there is a gap between the link you are hovering over and the items that will be displayed.

Remove the gap and it will work.

Comment: this is the good answer, problem is the gap

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are not using CSS correctly for this effect. What you want is the menu to stay displayed if the mouse moves from the heading to the list, else it should vanish. For that you can use Javascript. Something like:

```
$("#heading").mouseenter(function(e) {
  if ($(e.ralatedTraget).prop('id') != 'menu') {
   $("#menu").stop().fadeIn(500);
   }
});
$("#heading").mouseleave(function(e) {
   if ($(e.ralatedTraget).prop('id') != 'menu') {
     $("#menu").stop().fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: note that jQuery is not the answer to [everything](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: He he, that was hilarious! Of course I know jQuery is not the solution to everything, but in this case I surmised that the user plans to do more things, like letting the menu stay when the user hovers from there to the heading, etc. So I thought jQuery might help there.

Answer (score 0):

It's the structure of your CSS.  I've built a simple dropdown you should be able to use or copy and implement into what you have.

[Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/kE4yb/)